# Accessing dictionary key values within the same dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

Might be a silly question but I'm wondering about something:

Let's say i have the following dictionary:

```
dict = {
   'nr_one' : 5,
   'nr_two' : 6,
   'nr_three' : *sum of the above numbers*
}
```

Is there a `self` thing within the dictionary allowing me to declare a new key where the value would be the result of an operation with two of the dictionary's values?

Comment: Nope. it would become like a formula then. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, no. That's very abstract, why the two dict numbers? Why not three of the values? What if you want more values, or just three first values?

But as far as adding the values, you can use `sum` for adding all the numbers:

```
my_dict['total'] = sum(value for value in my_dict.values())
```

Also, remember to avoid naming a dictionary `dict`, which will override the built in function with that same name.

By the way, demo:

```
>>> my_dict = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c': 3, 'd':4}
>>> my_dict['total'] = sum([value for value in my_dict.values()])
>>> my_dict
{'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2, 'd': 4, 'total': 10}
```

To do another kind of basic operations, you'll have to create your own functions. For example, multiplying:

```
>>> def multiply(d):
    values = d.values()
    result = 1
    for v in d.values():
        result *= v
    return result

>>> multiply(my_dict)
240 
#shorter version, as @hcwhsa suggested:
>>> import operator
>>> reduce(operator.mul, my_dict.values())
240
```

Comment: Thanks for the input and clarification. Also, for the naming hint :)

Comment: @aiKid, You do not need square brackets, which will force building a list. Without square brackets, the parameter of *sum* behaves as a generator - which can make a big difference with big data set

Comment: You can shorten your `multiply` function to: `reduce(operator.mul, my_dict.values())`, and drop the `[]` from `sum()`, no need to create a list in memory.

Comment: I just realized that we can do that.. Thanks for the tips!